# Change the On/Off text of a toggle button Android

Tags: android, togglebutton

I just [changed the background of a `ToggleButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657471/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-toggle-button-in-android), and now I'm looking to change the ON/OFF text that comes up with it.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You can use the following to set the text from the code:

```
toggleButton.setText(textOff);
// Sets the text for when the button is first created.

toggleButton.setTextOff(textOff);
// Sets the text for when the button is not in the checked state.

toggleButton.setTextOn(textOn);
// Sets the text for when the button is in the checked state.
```

To set the text using xml, use the following:

```
android:textOff="The text for the button when it is not checked."
android:textOn="The text for the button when it is checked."
```

This information is from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)

Comment: however it doesn't work on e.i. samsung and htc phones

Comment: Serafins, that's not right. It does work on Samsung and HTC phones.

Comment: When updating the on and off text programatically the button doesn't redraw itself with the new text. You can force a redraw by calling setChecked(toggleButton.isChecked). Sounds ridiculous but its a hack to force redrawing. See [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792554/2590478).

Comment: It appears you no longer need toggleButton.setTextOff(textOff); and toggleButton.setTextOn(textOn);. The text for each toggled state will change by merely including the relevant xml characteristics.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work with `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` on some OEMs I have checked that!

Comment: You've call `toggleButton.setSelected(<false/true>)` after setting the ON/OFF text from code to force invalidate the button.

Comment: Nothing of the mentioned works for Nexus for either Switch and SwitchCompat. Only set in xml or use custom drawable

Answer (score 16):

In the example you link to, they are changing it to Day/Night by using `android:textOn` and `android:textOff`

Comment: I actually linked to a different question I had never seen before.  Thanks for pointing out the answer in my own question.

Answer (score 13):

Set the XML as:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/flashlightButton"
    style="@style/Button"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonStrobeLight"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
    android:text="ToggleButton"
    android:textOn="Light ON"
    android:textOff="Light OFF" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, you need to force refresh the view in order to make it work.

```
toggleButton.setTextOff(textOff);
toggleButton.requestLayout();

toggleButton.setTextOn(textOn);
toggleButton.requestLayout();
```

Comment: `requestLayout()` doesn't work but `setChecked()` does.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you no longer need toggleButton.setTextOff(textOff); and toggleButton.setTextOn(textOn);. The text for each toggled state will change by merely including the relevant xml characteristics. This will override the default ON/OFF text.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toggleText"
    android:textOff="ADD TEXT"
    android:textOn="CLOSE TEXT"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by 2 options:

> Option 1: By setting its xml attributes

```
 `android:textOff="TEXT OFF"
  android:textOn="TEXT ON"`
```

> Option 2: Programmatically
>
> Set the attribute onClick: methodNameHere (mine is toggleState)
>   Then write this code:

```
public void toggleState(View view) {
   boolean toggle = ((ToogleButton)view).isChecked();
   if (toggle){
       ((ToogleButton)view).setTextOn("TEXT ON");
   } else {
      ((ToogleButton)view).setTextOff("TEXT OFF");
   }
}
```

PS: it works for me, hope it works for you too